# Does ls -R make any sense with -d?

Tags: ls

I tried to use `ls -dR` but I don't see any difference with `ls -d`. Does `-R` do anything when there's also `-d`?

Comment: in simple experimentation, `-d` overrides `-R` ...

Comment: ... for the particular implementation(s) of `ls` you experimented with.

Answer (score 5):

[POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html):

> `-R`
>   Recursively list subdirectories encountered. When a symbolic link to a
>   directory is encountered, the directory shall not be recursively
>   listed unless the `-L` option is specified. **The use of `-R` with
>   `-d` or `-f` produces unspecified results.**

And that:

> This volume of POSIX.1-2017 is frequently silent about what happens
>   when mutually-exclusive options are specified. Except for -R, -d, and
>   -f, the ls utility is required to accept multiple options from each mutually-exclusive option set without treating them as errors and to
>   use the behavior specified by the last option given in each
>   mutually-exclusive set.

So, it may or may not make sense.